# How to apply each color to each geometry which i m feching from database

Tags: postgresql, polygon, openlayers, geometry, style

I have multiple geometry polygons in my fetched data from the database like below. I am trying to apply each color to each polygon geometry. How can I seperate each polygon and how can I apply each color to each individual polygon?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <title>Vector layer example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
#popup-content {
     background-color: lightgrey;
}


      .ol-popup {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
        filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        bottom: 12px;
        left: -50px;
        min-width: 280px;
      }
      .ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
        top: 100%;
        border: solid transparent;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
      }
      .ol-popup:after {
        border-top-color: white;
        border-width: 10px;
        left: 48px;
        margin-left: -10px;
      }
      .ol-popup:before {
        border-top-color: #cccccc;
        border-width: 11px;
        left: 48px;
        margin-left: -11px;
      }
      .ol-popup-closer {
        text-decoration: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        right: 8px;
      }
      .ol-popup-closer:after {
        content: "✖";
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
          <div id="map" class="map">
            <div id="popup" class="ol-popup"> 
             <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
            <div id="popup-content" >   </div>
        </div>
        </div>
         <div id="info" class="alert alert-success">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
    <script>

    $( function() {
    $( "#popup" ).draggable();
    $("#popup").resizable();

  } );
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');
var  style_g = new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0,255,255,0.6)',
                width: 1
              })
            });
var  style_k = new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0, 128, 0,0.6)',
                width: 1
              })
            });
var  style_l = new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0, 128, 128,0.6)',
                width: 1
              })
            });
var  style_m = new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255,0.6)',
                width: 1
              })
            });         
             styles_g = [style_g,style_k,style_l,style_m];
             for (i=0;i<styles_g.length;i++)
             {


var vectorLayer4 = new ol.layer.Vector({
              maxResolution: 0.8,
              source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: 'pms_geom_php.php',
               format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                  defaultDataProjection:'EPSG:4326'
                })
              }),
              style: styles_g[i]
            });
            //alert(styles_g[i]);
             }
var popup = new ol.Overlay(({
    element: container,
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250
    }
}));
closer.onclick = function() {
  popup.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

var mapcenter = [79.60,23.44];
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
   new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
     url: 'http://localhost:8089/geoserver/manjula/wms',
                params: {'LAYERS': 'manjula:India_states_UT_geo_wgs84'}
        })
      }),
     vectorLayer4
  ],
  overlays: [popup],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
               center: mapcenter,
               zoom: 5,
               extent: [66.2329, 7.68083, 98.2223, 39.03874],
               maxZoom:16,
               minZoom: 4,
    })
});
var highlightStyleCache = {};
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector(),
        map: map,
        style: function (feature, resolution) {
            var text = resolution * 100000 < 10 ? feature.get('text') : '';
            if (!highlightStyleCache[text]) {
                highlightStyleCache[text] = new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#0000FF',
                        width: 2
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(192,192,192,0.7)'
                    }),
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                        text: text,
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#000'
                        }),
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: '#f00',
                            width: 3
                        })
                    })
                });
            }
            return highlightStyleCache[text];
        }
    });
var highlight;
    var displayFeatureInfo = function (pixel) {

        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature) {
            return feature;
        });

        var info = document.getElementById('info');
        if (feature) {
            info.innerHTML = '';

        } else {
            info.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        }

        if (feature !== highlight) {
            if (highlight) {

                featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
            }
            if (feature) {
                featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(feature);
            }
            highlight = feature;
        }
    };
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {

  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
  displayFeatureInfo(pixel);

  feature = evt.coordinate;
        var hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(feature);
        click_long = feature[1].toFixed(2);
        click_lat = feature[0].toFixed(2);
        alert("lat"+click_lat);
        alert("lat"+click_lat);
        var xmlhttp;
            if( window.XMLHttpRequest )
                            {
                                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );

                            }
                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function( )
                            {
                              if( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 )
                              { 
                                content.innerHTML = '<p style="color:orange">You clicked here:</p>'+ xmlhttp.responseText;
                              }

                            }

                            var url = "pms_spatial_inc.php";
                            url=url+"?hdms="+hdms;
                            url=url+"&click_lat="+click_lat;
                            url=url+"&click_long="+click_long;
                            xmlhttp.open( "GET", url, true );
                            xmlhttp.send(); 
                            popup.setPosition(feature);

});
  map.addOverlay( popup);

map.on('click', function (evt) {
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);

    })
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. Here is the geometry code

   ```
   <?php

    $host        = "host=192.168.106.81";
      $port        = "port=5432";
      $dbname      = "dbname=pms";
      $credentials = "user=postgres password=postgres";
        $db = pg_connect("$host $port $dbname $credentials");
      if(!$db){
         echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
      } 


   $data_query = "SELECT  ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) As geometry from three";

   $data = pg_query($db,$data_query);


    $geojson = array(
         'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
         'features'  => array()

      );

      while($edge=pg_fetch_assoc($data)) {

           $feature = array(
               'type' => 'Feature',
               'geometry' => $edge['geometry'],

                           );
        array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
      }
     echo str_replace('}"','}',str_replace('"{"','{"',stripslashes(json_encode($geojson))));


   ?>
   ```

   Here I am fetching 4 geometry coloums from database as output here for this geometry I want to apply the color to each individual polygon.

I thought of applying array with list of style tags  as below

```
var  style_g = new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0,255,255,0.6)',
                width: 1
              })
            });
var  style_k = new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0, 128, 0,0.6)',
                width: 1
              })
            });
var  style_l = new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0, 128, 128,0.6)',
                width: 1
              })
            });
var  style_m = new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255,0.6)',
                width: 1
              })
            });         
             styles_g = [style_g,style_k,style_l,style_m];
             for (i=0;i<styles_g.length;i++)
             {


var vectorLayer4 = new ol.layer.Vector({
              maxResolution: 0.8,
              source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: 'pms_geom_php.php',
               format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                  defaultDataProjection:'EPSG:4326'
                })
              }),
              style: styles_g[i]
            });
            //alert(styles_g[i]);
             }
```